# C# program with COM port going NOT RESPONDING

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wcf, serial-port

I have C#/.NET program which uses a COM port and SQL CE Database with a WCF service. Sometimes the program becomes unresponsive (the window freezes) and even in debug mode I cannot the reason.

I can restart the program after restarting my PC or the COM port. The problem isn't with my COM port problem because I have tried it on many PCs and all have the same problem.

How could I resolve this?

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        labeltimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if (timerstarted == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        timerstarted = true;
        _CARDCODE = 0;
        string error = "";
        bool hasbassed = false;
        if (this._Close == true)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            if (i < 8)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            to[0] = (byte)(128 + i);
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Write(to, 0, 1);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                ListViewItem Lvi = new ListViewItem((++rowcount).ToString());
                Lvi.SubItems.Add("");
                Lvi.SubItems.Add("");
                Lvi.SubItems.Add("Disconnected");
                Lvi.SubItems.Add("");
                listView.Items.Add(Lvi);
                StartPort();
            }


            if (progressBar.Value >= 1500)
                progressBar.Value = 0;
            else
                progressBar.Value += 10;

            if (serialPort1.BytesToRead != 0)
            {

                byte[] data = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead];
                from = new byte[3];
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    ListViewItem LVi = new ListViewItem((++rowcount).ToString());
                    LVi.SubItems.Add("");
                    LVi.SubItems.Add("");
                    LVi.SubItems.Add("Disconnected");
                    LVi.SubItems.Add("");
                    listView.Items.Add(LVi);
                    StartPort();
                }
                // data.Length == 4 by Button or HassPassed
                if (data.Length == 4)
                {
                    if (data[1] > 2)
                        DBS.AddButtonPass(data[0], data[1] / 4);
                    else
                    {
                        DBS.EditPass((int)data[0]);
                        timerstarted = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }
                else if ((data[data.Length - 1] != 255) || (data.Length < 4))
                {
                    from[0] = data[0];
                    from[1] = 0;
                    from[2] = 0;
                    serialPort1.Write(from, 0, 3);
                    timerstarted = false;
                    return;
                }

                //RegistoringSubscriber_ID Add Subscriber Card
                else if ((RegistoringSubscriber_ID > 0) && (RegisterCheckpoint != 0) && (data[0] == RegisterCheckpoint))
                {
                    Registoring = false;
                    if (RegistorNewCard(Convert.ToInt32(data[2].ToString() + data[3].ToString() + data[4].ToString())) > 0)
                        FormBringPC.AnswerType = 1;
                    else
                        FormBringPC.AnswerType = 2;
                    RegistoringSubscriber_ID = 0;

                    error = "register card";
                }
                // RegistoringSubscriber_ID < 0 Add Bonus Card
                else if ((RegistoringSubscriber_ID < 0) && (RegisterCheckpoint != 0) && (data[0] == RegisterCheckpoint))
                {
                    Registoring = false;
                    if (RegistorBonusCard(Convert.ToInt32(data[2].ToString() + data[3].ToString() + data[4].ToString())) > 0)
                        FormBringPC.AnswerType = 1;
                    else
                        FormBringPC.AnswerType = 2;
                    RegistoringSubscriber_ID = 0;

                    error = "register Bonus card";
                }
                else if ((List_Checkpoint_ID.Contains(data[0]) && ((data[1] == 130) || (data[1] == 129))))
                {
                   //     DBS.EditPass((int)data[0]);
                }
                else if ((List_Checkpoint_ID.Contains(data[0]) && (data.Length == 7)))
                {
                    _CARDCODE = Convert.ToInt32(data[2].ToString() + data[3].ToString() + data[4].ToString());
                    GlobalTypes.InvalidPass pass = DBS.CheckPassStatus(_CARDCODE, (int)data[0], (int)data[1]);
                    if (pass == GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.Valid)
                    {
                        from[0] = data[0];
                        from[1] = 1;
                        from[2] = 1;
                        serialPort1.Write(from, 0, 3);
                        LBTitle.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                        hasbassed = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        from[0] = data[0];
                        from[1] = 0;
                        from[2] = 0;
                        serialPort1.Write(from, 0, 3);
                        switch (pass)
                        {
                            case GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.InvalidCard:
                                {
                                    error = "Չգրանցված քարտ";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.InvalidCount:
                                {
                                    error = "Այց. քանակ";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.InvalidGraphic:
                                {
                                    error = "Ժամանակ hh:mm:ss";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.InvalidPeriod:
                                {
                                    error = "Ժամանակահատված xxxx.dd.yyy";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.InvalidStatus:
                                {
                                    error = "Հառացված աբոնենտ";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case GlobalTypes.InvalidPass.InvalidSuscribe:
                                {
                                    error = "Անհայտ բաժանորդ";
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    error = "esim inch";
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ((List_Checkpoint_ID.Contains(data[0]) && (data.Length > 0)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] ticket = new byte[data.Length - 6];

                        for (int ii = 0; ii < data.Length - 6; ii++)
                        {
                            ticket[ii] = data[ii + 2];
                        }

                        _CARDCODE = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ticket.ToArray()));
                        GlobalTypes.HasPass pass = DBS.CheckTicketPassStatus(_CARDCODE, (int)data[0], (int)data[1]);
                        if (pass == GlobalTypes.HasPass.TruePass)
                        {
                            from[0] = data[0];
                            from[1] = 1;
                            from[2] = 1;
                            serialPort1.Write(from, 0, 3);
                            LBTitle.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                            hasbassed = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            from[0] = data[0];
                            from[1] = 0;
                            from[2] = 0;
                            serialPort1.Write(from, 0, 3);
                            switch (pass)
                            {
                                case GlobalTypes.HasPass.CardNotFound:
                                    {
                                        error = "Not registored ticket";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case GlobalTypes.HasPass.CardRepeat:
                                    {
                                        error = "ReEntring";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case GlobalTypes.HasPass.ValidationPeriodError:
                                    {
                                        error = "Ժամանակ hh:mm:ss";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case GlobalTypes.HasPass.SeasonError:
                                    {
                                        error = "Ժամանակահատված xxxx.dd.yyy";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case GlobalTypes.HasPass.WeekOfDayError:
                                    {
                                        error = "Day of Weak";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                default:
                                    {
                                        error = "esim inch";
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { timerstarted = false; return; }
                }
                if (rowcount >= 10)
                {
                    rowcount = 0;
                    listView.Items.Clear();
                }
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem((++rowcount).ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(data[0].ToString());
                if (data.Length == 4)
                    hasbassed = true;
                if (((data[1] == 2) || (data[1] == 8)) && ((data.Length == 4) || (Dictionary_Chekpoint[data[0]].CheckPointType == 2)))
                {
                    lvi.SubItems.Add("Ելք");
                }
                else
                {
                    lvi.SubItems.Add("Մուտք");
                }
                if (data.Length != 4)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(_CARDCODE.ToString());
                else
                    lvi.SubItems.Add("Հերթապահ");
                lvi.SubItems.Add(error);
                if (hasbassed == true)
                {
                    lvi.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvi.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
                }
                listView.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Serial port is closed!", "RS232 tester", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        timerstarted = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        timerstarted = false;
        return;
    }
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is this right??? this is my code what repats

Comment: Even if you are not able to isolate the location of the issue, you can at least add some logs around the serial port calls to find out which one is blocking your application main thread. That would allow you to provide a short piece of code illustrating your problem instead of dumping your whole code an expect us to do your job. I also quite convinced that Justin is right and that you're doing serial port blocking calls in your GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

C# programs show as NOT RESPONDING whenever there is processing happening in the main UI thread that is preventing UI processing.  The general answer here is to push that work into a different thread, so that UI events can continue to process (see references below for more information).  In the case of serial ports, the easiest thing to do is hook the SerialPort.DataReceived event instead of polling it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Ref:

[GUI not responding while fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101730/gui-not-responding-while-fetching-data)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246911-c%23-multi-threading-in-a-gui-environment/

Comment: this cannot help me , because, my UI is not important, important is programm, that answers to COM  port read/write on DB , if UI works but my second threade not responding thats not help me, i need to resolve problem ,

Comment: If the UI is not important, than you should consider re-writing the code as a service instead of a winforms app.

Comment: in my winform im showing the shchedule online and it going faster , if i create an service insteade from form my queries going slower,

Comment: It's hard to be sure from what you've given us, but it seems like you are doing everything in one thread (the UI thread).  So, any one thing taking a long time will cause the rest of them to be delayed.  For the best performance, you'll want to separate the UI, serial port, and database access into different threads, or at least switch them to events so they don't block as bad.  Switching from WinForms to a service doesn't fix that underlying problem, it just shifts things around; I suggested it merely because you said the UI was not important (it sounds like the UI actually IS important).

Comment: that what i show in UI is not VERY IMPORTANT important that the programm continue work...thanks about threads i think that will help i will try it today